# Best way to count view when 1 page is cached in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I want ask best way to count view when 1 page is cached in cakePHP.

When a page is cached , I use javascript send request to server to + view for post. But i think it cause server is overload.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Your objective is page-view analytics? Have you considered a third-party solution like [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/)?

Comment: i use google analytics, but still count view to show for user

Answer (score 1):

Mike Han's response is incorrect. Cached pages in Cake also bypass app_controller. you will need to do an ajax call from the cached page to some action which increments your view-count database field.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect controller is still in action though the view is cached. Or at least beforeFilter of app controller may still be working. You could do the count there.